# Block Configuration Form Returning Unexpected Value

Tags: forms, blocks, configuration

I'm trying to build a block configuration form. Here's my blockForm code:

```
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['resolve_ip_addresses'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this->t('Resolve IP Addresses'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['resolve_ip_addresses'],
      '#description' => $this->t('Resolve IP addresses to return host names for log file entries.'),
    ];

    $form['log_file_path'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Log File Path'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['log_file_path'],
      '#description' => $this->t('The full file system path to the log file to be parsed.'),
    ];

    $form['log_file_format'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => $this->t('Log Format'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['log_file_format'],
      '#options' => [
        0 => $this->t('Common Log Format (Apache)'),
        1 => $this->t('Combined Log Format (Nginx)'),
        2 => $this->t('Other'),
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        'name' => 'field_log_file_format',
      ],
    ];
    $form['custom_log_format'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => '60',
      '#placeholder' => $this->t('Enter log format'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['custom_log_format'],
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => 'custom-log-format',
      ],
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="field_log_file_format"]' => ['value' => 2],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }
```

The form seems to be displayed properly. I'm having an issue getting the value for the "log_file_format" field. Here's my blockSubmit code:

```
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['resolve_ip_addresses'] = $form_state->getValue('resolve_ip_addresses');
    $this->configuration['log_file_path'] = $form_state->getValue('log_file_path');
    $this->configuration['log_file_format'] = $form_state->getValue('log_file_format');
    $this->configuration['custom_log_format'] = $form_state->getValue('custom_log_format');
  }
```

The problem is that the value returned from $form_state->getValue('log_file_format') is always 0 (zero), no matter what value I select on the form and save the block. All of the other values are correct. Interestingly, the "custom_log_format" field correctly switches visibility on the form when the "Other" option (value 2) is selected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think it's sure custom name attribute `'name' => 'field_log_file_format',` messing it up. Try removing that to see if it then works

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the problem. Removing that attribute breaks the visibility state for the "custom_log_format" field, though. How can I toggle the visibility so that the field is only visible if "Other" is selected? Changing ":input[name="field_log_file_format"]" to ":input[name="log_file_format"]" isn't working.

Comment: Another interesting point: my original code was based on samples found on Drupal's own documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields

Comment: Remove 'name' => 'field_log_file_format', and change ':input[name="field_log_file_format"]' to ':input[name="log_file_format"]' should work. Because when you remove the attributes name, Drupal will add name='log_file_format' to that radios field. You check the #states of 'custom_log_format' on that radios field ('log_file_format' by default)

Comment: In case you modify those both not help(in saving and switch visibility),  try replace ['value' => 2] to ['value' => '2']. The numeric and string may the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried both changes. Getting rid of the "name" attribute fixed the problem with the value of the log_file_format field, but the custom_log_format field is still visible. Changing ['value' => 2] to ['value' => '2'] made no difference.

Comment: Got it: I needed to change "':input[name="field_log_file_format"]'" to "':input[name="settings[log_file_format]"]'" to get the visibility toggle working. I don't know why, but inspecting the form elements as they were displayed in my browser showed that the name attribute of the radio elements was "settings[log_file_format]".

Answer (score 0):

The fix suggested by @unusedspoon took care of the radio element value problem. The form element value was properly set after removing the `'name' => 'field_log_file_format'` attribute from the `'log_file_format'` form element - but that broke the visibility toggle for the `'custom_log_format'`. The fix for that was to change `':input[name="field_log_file_format"]'` to `':input[name="settings[log_file_format]"]'`.